# Following a tutorial and not getting the same result

Tags: displacement

So I am following a tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQCS7Hk_G6Y&ab_channel=WiresoulStudio (2017)

and my result looks like:
[image]

Whereas, in the video I am following, the uploader's image looks like :

[image]

I am using the same image for following this tutorial. This video was uploaded in 2017 and since then, Blender may have changed quite a bit and some options were different but I tried my best to select the closest.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender 2.8 and higher requires the *Displacement* node to work with the *Displacement* of the *Material Output* node. In Blender 2.79 you can plug the color directly into the *Displacement* slot as shown in the video. This no longer works in the later versions of Blender.

[image: shader node setup]

The *Displacement* node has a *Scale* value which does the job of the *Math* node as shown in the video. Set it to a value of `1.320` to get a similar result as in the video. The *Midlevel* value needs to be set to `0.000`. It defines the "ground level" of the displaced image.